# Condensing this code

Tags: php, sql, refactoring

I have the following code I want to run, but the problem is $this->type is set when the class is created by specifying either petition, proposal, or amendment. As you can see my $sql statement is a UNION of all three, and I want to specify which table (pet,prop,or amend) each row of data comes from.

```
public function userProposals() {
    $username = User::getUsername();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM petition WHERE author = '$username'
    UNION SELECT * FROM proposition WHERE author = '$username'
    UNION SELECT * FROM amendment WHERE author = '$username'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $state = User::userState();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // $this->type needs to specify pet,prop,amend
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[id]</td>
            <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=$this->type&id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></td>
            <td>$this->type</td>
            <td>$state</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

As you can see, $this->type will only say one of the three. To get my function work how i wanted to, I did this (which I feel is too long & there must be a shorter way).

```
public function userProposals() {
    $username = User::getUsername();
    $state = User::userState();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM petition WHERE author = '$username'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[id]</td>
            <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=petition&id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></td>
            <td>Petition</td>
            <td>$state</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM proposition WHERE author = '$username'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[id]</td>
            <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=proposition&id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></td>
            <td>Proposition</td>
            <td>$state</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM amendment WHERE author = '$username'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$row[id]</td>
            <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=amendment&id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></td>
            <td>Amendment</td>
            <td>$state</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally do something like the following:

```
public function userProposals() {
    $username = User::getUsername();
    $state = User::userState();
    $tables = array('petition', 'proposition', 'amendment');
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $label = ucwords($table);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE author = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "
                <tr>
                <td>$row[id]</td>
                <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=$table&id=$row[id]'>$row[title]</a></td>
                <td>$label</td>
                <td>$state</td>
                </tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: +1 good point!  You need to watch out for users entering nasty bits of SQL in their user names (aka, "SQL injection attacks").  @too much php's call to mysql_real_escape_string() makes sure that the malicious SQL is safely put inside a string constant and can't hurt your application.

Comment: @nothingmuch, while this is funny, it's not at all helpful in answering the specific question. It may not even be remotely relevant, since you have *no* idea what the User::getUsername() function does; it may always return sanitized values safe for use in queries.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks

Comment: that is irrelevant, the implied type of the User::getUsername() expression is a string representing a username, that is not an encoded string for consumption by an SQL database.
<br/>
The code that generates the SQL should be responsible for cleaning up the string, because if someone later refactors User::getUsername without thinking of all the possible usage contexts they might introduce an sql injection attack after the fact.
<br/>
I felt that others have answered the question but did not address this issue, and that since the poster is looking for general advice, this is relevant.

Comment: That's a good point on the refactoring (other than the fact that you could equally imply the string was sanitized) but I still see nothing in the Q asking for general advice. It specifically asked for how to compress the code, not for a general critique - in my opinion (and it's only *my* opinion), yours is a good answer, just not to this question. And so far, the only markdown I've seen working in comments is *italics* - in Q&A fields, there seems to be much better support.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the modified SQL:

```
SELECT 'petition' as typ,title,id FROM petition
  WHERE author = '$username'
UNION SELECT 'proposition' as typ,title,id FROM proposition
  WHERE author = '$username'
UNION SELECT 'amendment' as typ,totle,id FROM amendment
  WHERE author = '$username'"
```

and then use the `typ` from each returned row `($row[typ])` instead of `$this->type`?

The whole thing should be:

```
public function userProposals() {
  $username = User::getUsername();
  $sql = "SELECT 'petition' as typ,id,title FROM petition
            WHERE author = '$username'
    UNION SELECT 'proposition' as typ,id,title FROM proposition
            WHERE author = '$username'
    UNION SELECT 'amendment' as typ,id,title FROM amendment
            WHERE author = '$username'"
  $query = mysql_query($sql);
  $state = User::userState();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>$row[id]</td>
      <td><a href='viewproposal.php?type=$row[typ]&id=$row[id]'>
        $row[title]
      </a></td>
      <td>$row[typ]</td>
      <td>$state</td>
    </tr>";
  }
}
```

based on what was in your question.

Comment: I got an error: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM petition WHERE author = 'test44' UNION SELECT 'proposition' as typ,*' at line 1. 

From $query = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Apologies, @Farhan, I forgot you could either use * or fields but not both. I've fixed it to use the specific fields (which you might want to do anyway to minimize traffic sent across the wire).

Comment: Strange, you should at least be able to use: SELECT 'petition' AS  typ, petition.* FROM petition ...